# Animate (loop) a dashed SVG line

Tags: animation, svg

After finishing the animation, I need to keep the dotted arrow animated.. like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZpR9DyM_qs

I tried to add:

```
<animate attributeName="d" from="M0 0 C0 0, 0 0, 0 0" to="M0 0 C47.85 -13.4, 239.25 -67.01, 287.1 -80.41"
      begin="1000ms" dur="900ms" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />'
```

but it's starts from the beginning.. My code:

```
   <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 347.09505655750377 140.4105292643194"
 width="694.1901131150075" height="280.8210585286388">

 <rect x="0" y="0" width="347.09505655750377" height="140.4105292643194" fill="#ffffff" />
 <g stroke-linecap="round">
   <g transform="translate(30 110.4105292643194) rotate(0 143.54752827875188 -40.2052646321597)">
     <path d="M0 0 C0 0, 0 0, 0 0" stroke="#495057" stroke-width="4.5" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="8 12" opacity="0">
       <animate attributeName="d" from="M0 0 C0 0, 0 0, 0 0" to="M0 0 C47.85 -13.4, 239.25 -67.01, 287.1 -80.41"
         begin="1000ms" dur="900ms" fill="freeze" />
       <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="1" begin="1000ms" dur="900ms" fill="freeze" /> 
     </path>
   </g>
   <g transform="translate(30 110.4105292643194) rotate(0 143.54752827875188 -40.2052646321597)">
     <path d="M262.72 -62.93 C262.72 -62.93, 262.72 -62.93, 262.72 -62.93" stroke="#495057" stroke-width="4.5"
       fill="none" opacity="0">
       <animate attributeName="d" from="M262.72 -62.93 C262.72 -62.93, 262.72 -62.93, 262.72 -62.93"
         to="M262.72 -62.93 C268.12 -66.8, 273.53 -70.68, 287.1 -80.41" begin="1900ms" dur="300ms" fill="freeze" />
       <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="1" begin="1900ms" dur="300ms" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
   </g>
   <g transform="translate(30 110.4105292643194) rotate(0 143.54752827875188 -40.2052646321597)">
     <path d="M257.18 -82.69 C257.18 -82.69, 257.18 -82.69, 257.18 -82.69" stroke="#495057" stroke-width="4.5"
       fill="none" opacity="0">
       <animate attributeName="d" from="M257.18 -82.69 C257.18 -82.69, 257.18 -82.69, 257.18 -82.69"
         to="M257.18 -82.69 C263.82 -82.18, 270.45 -81.68, 287.1 -80.41" begin="2200ms" dur="300ms" fill="freeze" />
       <animate attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="1" begin="2200ms" dur="300ms" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
   </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Please help

Comment: The only thing that I see in the video are two lines (one dashed and one dotted) that are animated. What do you mean by "start from the beginning" and what would the preferred state to start from be? You could define more animate elements that have different values in the from attribute and have them start one after the other -- something like that?

Comment: @chrwahl yes the 2 lines.. please check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cutsW7Q7uo video of my actual result.

Comment: Please provide a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Seriously, I doubt, your animation can't be reduced to a running snippet - sharing youtube links is rather over complicated. Otherwise there are a options to share also react (or other framework based) examples.

Comment: @herrstrietzel hi, I changed my approach to fix the problem.. please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example I split out the arrow in two elements so that they can be animates separately. The "running" dash array is made with a mask that is animated. And the initial animation of the path is made by animating the dash offset. The three animations are timed, so that the two are following the one called `primaty`. The animation of the arrow head is made with a white rectangle that covers the arrow and is then animated "away" from the viewbox of the marker.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="8" refY="5"
      markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
      <path d="M 1 1 L 9 5 L 1 9" fill="none" stroke="black"
        stroke-width="1" maske="url(#mask_arrow)" />
      <rect width="10" height="10" fill="white" x="0">
        <animate attributeName="x" values="0;10" dur="300ms"
          begin="primary.end - 300ms" repeatCount="none" fill="freeze" />
      </rect>
    </marker>
    <mask id="mask_arrow">
      <path d="M 5 5 Q 65 40 80 10" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"
        fill="none" marker-end="url(#arrow)"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask_dash">
      <path d="M 5 5 Q 65 40 80 10" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"
        stroke-dasharray="5" fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="0"
        pathLength="100">
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-100"
          dur="5s" begin="primary.begin" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <path d="M 5 5 Q 65 40 80 10" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
    stroke-dasharray="100" stroke-dashoffset="100" pathLength="100"
    fill="none" mask="url(#mask_dash)">
    <animate id="primary" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
      values="100;0" dur="5s" repeatCount="none" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  <path d="M 5 45 Q 65 40 80 10" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"
    fill="none" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but in my case, I can't split the SVG. since I import into my app different objects (rectangles, lines, arrows... ) with different durations and lengths

Comment: hello again, I changed my approach to fix the problem.. please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: i fixed to problem with this line: <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="300;0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" />